# How to delete MobaXterm "Custom sessions"

Tags: session, xterm

In [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/), there is a "Custom Sessions" node that contains all the same items as my bookmarked "User Sessions":

[image: MobaXterm snapshot]

It's annoying, but there doesn't seem to be any way to delete the Custom Sessions node.

Does anyone know how to get rid of it?

Comment: Added links, capitalization, formatting, grammar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look for the file Custom.mxtpro, it should be in your MobaXterm install directory. It's a zip file, containing (among others) a file named Custom.bookmarks.ini . Delete this ini file from Custom.mxtpro, and the "Custom Sessions" node will be gone.

Comment: Tip for 7zip users on Windows:  If you're getting "access is denied" when trying to delete Custom.bookmarks.ini from Custom.mxtpro then you're going to need to re-run 7zip as an administrator.  You don't have to add 7z to your PATH and look up the cmd/powershell syntax or anything gross like that.  Just right-click on the "7-Zip File Manager" in the start menu and choose More>"Run as Administrator"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue deleting sessions.  I would delete them and they would reappear there when I restarted the application.  I even tried reinstalling the application only to see all the bookmarks there.

Then I found a file C:\Users[username]\Documents\MobaXterm\MobaXterm.ini that has all the bookmarks listed in there.  If you edit that file you should be able to get rid of the unwanted bookmarks.

Comment: Not what I was looking for, I can delete my bookmarks but the issue is not able to delete "Custom Sessions"